# Adjust layout width according to window width

Tags: layout, width

**I've enclosed a code of a layout. This is a form layout. How to adjust that layout width according to browser window size.I've tried this code but couldnt get good results.Some people calling it has "Liquid layout" that may be real.i've no idea about it.plz do help.**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<!--body-->
<body style="background-color:#F2F2F2" onload="showField();">

<!--table starts here-->
<table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"    style="background-color:#FFF;">//table
<tr>
<td><table width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background- color:#FFF">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="23" bgcolor="#ffffff"><img src="" width="23" height="45" border="0"  />      </td>
    <td width="606" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
    <td width="148" align="right" valign="middle" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#999999;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="23" bgcolor="#ffffff"><img src="" width="23" height="45" border="0" />      </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#6db33f"></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#6db33f" style="font-family: SimHei, SimSun, Arial; font-size:32px; color:#FFFFFF;">
    Example<br />
    <span style="font-size:14px;"></span></td>
    <td width="23" bgcolor="#6db33f">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </table></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>

<table width="750" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <!--form goes here-->
    <form name="TheForm" action="" method="post" dfield="longForm" onsubmit="return Form1_Validator(this)">


    <!--This is a nested table-->
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:#FFF;-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc; -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;">
      <tr>
            <td valign="top">

              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:#F2F2F2">
                <tr>
                  <td>

                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#F2F2F2;">


                        <tr>
                        <td height="35" bgcolor="#6DB33F" style="color: #FFF; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;"></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#6DB33F">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left" bgcolor="#6DB33F">&nbsp;
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td height="25">First Name<span style="color: #6699cc;">* </span>:    </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left">
                          <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" size="40" onblur="trim(document.TheForm.lastName)" value=""  /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td width="36%" height="25" bgcolor="#EBEBEB">Last Name<span style="color: #6699cc;"> *</span>:</td>
                        <td width="1" bgcolor="#EBEBEB">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="63%" align="left" bgcolor="#EBEBEB">
                          <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" size="40" onblur="trim(document.TheForm.firstName)" value="" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td height="25">Email <span style="color: #6699cc;">*</span>:     </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left">
                          <input type="text" name="company" id="company" size="40" onblur="trim(document.TheForm.company)" value="" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" height="25">Phone <span style="color: #6699cc;">*</span>:</td>
                        <td bgcolor="#EBEBEB">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left" bgcolor="#EBEBEB">
                          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="40" onblur="trim(document.TheForm.email)" value="" /></td>
                         </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are CSS media queries an option? That way you could define global sizing per control based on the resolution. Say for a window resolution of 800px and below all textboxes have a width of 100px. When the window resolution is greater than 800px then the width for all textboxes could be 200px. This ia just a simple property example but you could define plenty inside your media query.